# notpad++ alternative for Mac OS with pretty print for JSON and XML

Tags: osx, xml, json, notepad++

I would like a notepad for Mac OS that pretty prints JSON and XML copied from a server console, just like notepad++ did on pc with JSON and XML plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Atom](https://atom.io). It provides XML and JSON syntax highlighting.

[image: Atom displaying a XML file]

On the lower right corner click on Plain text if auto-detection does not work (e.g. when copying example XML into the editor) and select XML or JSON.

Comment: I tried atom but if the text I copy is in 1 line, it doesn't pretty print it in multiple lines like notepad++ plugins.

Comment: Install the plugin **atom-beautify** for source beautifying (`apm install atom-beautify`). It takes code that is in one line and makes several lines with proper indentation. Is this what you want?

Comment: that is exactly what i want!

Answer (score 1):

**CudaText** works on macOS, and it has plugins for pretty printing of JSON and XML. They are named `JSON Format`, and `XML Format`. Install them via `Plugins / Addon Manager`.

To enable plugins, you must install Python engine from python.org.